# Pesquisa e exibição de resultados no select

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tenho dois campos, um "input" e um "select", queria que ao começar a digitar um nome de usuário no input automaticamente os options do select fossem populados com dados vindos do BD relacionados com o que eu estou digitando (Os nomes parecidos com o digitado).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dá uma olhada [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp), penso que é algo do género que vc precisa.

Comment: Muito bom mesmo, do jeito que eu queria, e simples, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou usar Select2?

Eu uso bastante e faz exatamente o que você quer.

[SELECT2](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax)